# Can a GPLv3 app be uploaded to the Windows Store?

Tags: gpl-3

Let's consider a GNU-GPLv3 desktop application.

It is not dual-licensable at all, for instance because a lot of code has been contributed as GNU-GPLv3 by people who can not be found anymore, so changing the license is not an option.

**QUESTION**: Can this app be uploaded to the Windows Store?

*([real-world case](https://anki.tenderapp.com/discussions/ankidesktop/19409-publish-anki-on-windows-store))*

Comment: A more detailed analysis which comes to the conclusion that there is no problem with that: http://www.jbkempf.com/blog/post/2012/Windows-Store-and-the-GPL I think in the Anki case, the last sentence in parenthesis is the actual reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.**

From [this article](http://www.jbkempf.com/blog/post/2012/Windows-Store-and-the-GPL) linked by Philipp, Microsoft's store allows app developers to specify any terms they desire for their application, and makes specific allowances for OSI-approved licenses.

The GPL's disclaimer of warranty/liability protects auxiliary distributors.

> THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS **AND/OR OTHER PARTIES** PROVIDE THE PROGRAM “AS IS” WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND

However, some other free software licenses do not, so they may not comply with the requirement that you disclaim Microsoft from warranty in addition to yourself.

Comment: The blog has been removed by author, but it has been [archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161211113352/http://www.jbkempf.com/blog/post/2012/Windows-Store-and-the-GPL).